# Slow Operation And No Response Body When Sending Byte Array Over HTTP To Client

Tags: c#, .net, http, model-view-controller

I have `List of objects` which contains property of type `byte array` which is image content. When I send this in `JSON format` from `server to client` there is `no response body` in Internet Explorer browser.  If I `send around 100 or 1000 rows` to client, there is no problem. If I send `more then 3000` rows of data there is `no response body`. Is there any `specific method or pattern` which I should use to send collection of byte array to client ?

Type:

```
class Image
{
   public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

MVC:

```
   var obj = new {
                    rows = Manager.GetImages() *//returns List<Image>*
            };

   return new JsonResult() {Data = obj, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

*the server returns json with collection of type Image* to client over http

Comment: Would ask that you post the code that does the sending.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpWebRequest class has a Chunked property that you can set to true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked(v=vs.100).aspx